# How to create animated videos like this link?

Tags: 3d, animation, adobe-after-effects, maya, modeling

https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=S5cFLTTIF30 
I want to be able to make videos like this link. I've installed AutoDesk Maya but can't find much online help for self learning it. If there is any other software to help me create videos like this link? I want a software which be easy to learn. And less time taking to create animated videos.
 Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Your best chance to make videos like this is to use [Blender](https://www.blender.org/).

It´s free, it can handle 3D modeling easily well, it´s documentation is thorough and it also has many tutorials available. Also, as a great feature, it has it´s own video editor included.

Nevertheless, be ready to spend at least three months learning, before making a simple video like the one provided.